# Azure DevOps Server 2020.1 analytics issue related to iteration creation

Tags: sql-server, azure-devops, tfs, azure-devops-server-2020, azure-analytics

When we're trying to look at the burn down report we face the error **"Iteration not found. Information about this iteration could not be found on the analytics service. If this iteration was recently created, please reload shortly."**

Investigating this issue we noticed the iterations being reported about don't exist in the database indeed. Moreover whenever we create a new iteration either in the project configuration or planning board the appropriate entries aren't created in the AnalyticsModel.tbl_Iteration in the Collection Database.
Such behavior appeared in the neighborhood of month ago. Formerly when we created new iteration items in Azure Devops Server UI all the entries related these iterations were created in the database as well. Also such problem doesn't occur in the other Collections.
Has anybody had the same issue before?

Comment: You're running a pretty old version. It may be a bug that was fixed years ago. Consider upgrading to a more recent version.

Comment: We had beat the issue by disabling and further enabling Analytics feature in the site collection.
Since our site collection database size is north of 2.5 Tb that process took 8 days, now analytics service is working above reproaches but we still don't know the root cause to prevent this issue coming again.